# How to put multiple text boxes in an email body?

Tags: c#, email, visual-studio-2012

I have currently set up a program that sends emails with the content of the text boxes. However now I need to put multiple text boxes into the body of the email. I have tried this:

```
mail.Body = textBox2.Text;
mail.Body = textBox3.Text;
```

And this:

```
mail.Subject = textBox1.Text;
mail.Body = textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text;
```

But none of it works. It works if there is 1 text box in each part but not 2. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can append strings with the `+` operator:

```
mail.Body = textBox2.Text + textBox3.Text;
```

Or with `string.Format`:

```
mail.Body = string.Format("{0}{1}", textBox2.Text, textBox3.Text);
```

Or a `StringBuilder`:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append(textBox2.Text);
sb.Append(textBox3.Text);
mail.Body = sb.ToString();
```